# Exercise from Lang's Algebra concerning normal subgroups of relatively prime order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Chapter 1, Exercise 13(a) Let $G$ be a group, and $H,N$ normal subgroups whose orders are relatively prime.  Show that
$xy=yx$ for all $x\in H$ and $y\in N$, and that $H\times N\cong HN$.

Clearly, $H\cap N=\{e\}$ where $e$ is the identity element, but I can't seem to show that every element of $H$ must commute with every element of $N$. I've tried considering $H$ acting on $N$ by conjugation. Taking a $y\in N$, we would like to show its orbit is $\{y\}$.
Since $|Hy|=(H:H_y)$ (Hy denoting the orbit of $y$)we see that $|Hy|$ divides $|H|$, but there's no guarantee that $|Hy|$ divides $|N|$.  Hint, anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Show that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \in H \cap N$, so that it must equal $e$.

Comment: Ah, I see $N$ normal implies $xyx^{-1}\in N$ and so $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in N$, and similarly $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in H$.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$xy(yx)^{-1}=(xyx^{-1})y^{-1}=x(yx^{-1}y^{-1})$

Now $xyx^{-1}\in K$ as $K$ is a normal subgroup

Also $yx^{-1}y^{-1}\in H $

Thus the above product is in $H\cap K=\{e\}$

So $xy=yx$